# Adding a route to a VLAN

Tags: routing, vlan, juniper-ex

I have a Juniper 3200 with a few different vlans, **10.0.0.0**, **10.100.0.0** and a **10.1.0.0**. the 10.0.0.0 and 10.100.0.0 are on the LAN side of the firewall and can talk to each other, but 10.1.0.0 needs to talk through the firewall. I'm trying to have them talk through a firewall with an access port plugged into port 33 for the LAN and 34 for the DMZ. How would I set the routing with out breaking the other VLANs?

```
route 10.0.0.0/24 next-hop 10.1.0.5 
route 10.1.0.0/24 next-hop 10.0.0.5
```

Is there an option for adding a route only to a specific VLAN? IE `route vlan.10 10.0.0.0/24 next-hop 10.1.0.5` (I know that's wrong, I guess that is what I would be looking for in a solution).

Comment: Are you routing on the Juniper 3200, or on the firewall itself?

Comment: @cpt_fink The Juniper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for routing-instances. 
You could create a new routing instance as type virtual router and add the vlan interface, then you will have a completely separated routing table.